# How to make a class's constructor unit testable when its instantiating a Guice module in it?

Tags: java, java-8, guice, factory, utility

I have the below mentioned class in a library module, which the clients will use to interact with database. I have a public constructor that takes a parameter from the user of this library, but the problem with this is that, its a Guice module getting instantiated inside this constructor. So when I try to write a unit test for this DataPersistence clasas, I cannot inject the module. I don't want the real Guice module to be instantiated because that will create database connections and all.

```
public class DataPersistence {
    
    private MyDAO myDao;

    public DataPersistence(MyConfig myConfig) {
        myDao = Guice.createInjector(new MyDataModule(myConfig)).getInstance(MyDAO.class);
    }
    
    public String createEntry(final CreateIndexInput createIndexInput) throws IOException {
        return myDao.createEntry(createIndexInput);
    }

    public int indexDocument(final String indexName, final String jsonDocument) throws IOException {
        return myDao.indexDocument(indexName, jsonDocument).status().getStatus();
    }

    public SearchResult searchDocument(final String indexName, final Map<String, Object> queryMap)
            throws IOException {
        return myDao.searchDocument(indexName, queryMap);
    }
}
```

How can I convert this class to a utility where I have a way to mock the Guice module without triggering the real module? I tried making the constructor private, and added a "create" method and made the class final. But this way, all the methods would become static, allowing the user to call the methods, without having to call the "create" method first where I instantiate the myDao class.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: don't make your class dependent on that constructor(?)... i mean, pass a factory as parameter that generates that value, so that you can mock the factory

Comment: The return type of `Guice.createInjector` is `com.google.inject.Injector`, but your `myDao` field is of type `MyDAO`. How does that work? Please [edit] your question to include the source codes of `MyDAO`, `MyConfig` and `MyDataModule` to your question. Explain how these classes are related to each other. If possible add a [mcve] of the problem you have. The trivial suggestion would be "use a different `MyConfig` configuration", but we have no Idea what your classes are doing.

Comment: @Progman thanks very much for the response. I edited the question to reflect the issue wiith injector. This is actually the main class of a library package that will be used by service consumers. Its the consumers who will be passing the MyConfig and I would like to know what would be a better design for this class where consumers can pass the data but this class is also not bound to the Guice module class.

Comment: @Berto99 could you share an example of how I could go about it? Struggling to wrap my head around how the consumer will then use it

Comment: @AnOldSoul Depending on how you want to build it, you can add a new interface `MyDAOBuilder`, which you add to the parameter list of the `DataPersistence` constructor. It has a method to build the `MyDAO` object. You can use one implementation to use your normal Guice stuff and you can use a different implementation for your unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
public interface Config{ ... }

public class MyConfig implements Config{ ... }

public interface InjectorFactory {
  public MyDAO generate();
}

public class MyInjectorFactory{
  private MyConfig myConfig;
  public InjectorFactory(MyConfig myConfig){
    this.myConfig = myConfig;
  }
  public MyDAO generate(){
    return Guice.createInjector(new MyDataModule(myConfig)).getInstance(MyDAO.class);
  }
}

public class DataPersistence { 
  private MyDAO myDao;
  public DataPersistence(InjectorFactory factory) {
    myDao = factory.generate();
  }
}
```

Then to test, you can build `DataPersistence` with a mocked `InjectorFactory` that returns a mocked `MyDAO`

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I have a quick question. So in my case, consumers of my library will call "DataPersistence" class passing the MyConfig (This class has the methods clients are looking for). According to the design you proposed, should they implement MyInjectorFactory themselves to pass MyConfig?

Comment: Also what do you think about passing "MyConfig" as a parameter to the "generate" method and remove the constructor, making the "generate" method static?

Comment: you should pretty much never use static method, because you can't then mock them

Comment: @AnOldSoul yes, they should inherit the InjectorFactory that returns their configuration... but for example if you are using dependency injection, you don't need the factory

Comment: but it depends, for example if the Injector has always the same configuration (so makes sense to have it as a Singleton), than you can actually have the factory as static, and the factory generates the objects using a Config that user "saves" through  a static method

Comment: also, you can have a look at "Java SPI" (service providers)